# how to set up the ipython terminal such that pandas can use whole screen

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I have a big screen and would like pandas to use all space.

I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971449/how-do-i-increase-the-cell-width-of-the-ipython-notebook-in-my-browser), but pandas still breaks the line. As you can see in  the following screen shot, the error message uses the whole screen, but pandas part does not.

[image]

Comment: Start here http://stackoverflow.com/a/38489412/2336654

Comment: @piRSquared Thank you. It works for me.