# How to print a specific row of a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a massive DataFrame, and I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: ("Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot", 'occurred at index 159220')
```

I've already dropped nulls, and checked dtypes for the DataFrame so I have no guess as to why it's failing on that row.

How do I print out just that row (at index 159220) of the DataFrame?

Comment: `print(df.iloc[[index]])`

Answer (score 144, accepted):

When you call `loc` with a scalar value, you get a `pd.Series`. That series will then have one `dtype`.  If you want to see the row as it is in the dataframe, you'll want to pass an array like indexer to `loc`.

Wrap your index value with an additional pair of square brackets

```
print(df.loc[[159220]])
```

Comment: I've seen 3 different answers, (df.loc[[]], df.ix[], and df.iloc[]) is there a difference between them? Or an advantage of one over the others?

Comment: @Acoustic77 yes. ix will be deprecated. And I explain the purpose of the double bracket

Comment: got it, and is there an advantage of loc over iloc?

Comment: @Acoustic77 loc grabs things that are actually in the index. iloc grabs by position. Sometimes they are the same. No preference of one or the other. Depends on what you need.

Comment: If there are more columns (60 in my case) it is hiding many columns. Is there any way to print with these columns

Comment: @Sandeep does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38489412/2336654

Comment: with many columns, most of them are hidden. plus, it does not just print the row, it prints col numbers, column titles. if you want to print the data from the row with commas and without column names and other stuff, this solution is not good

Answer (score 126):

To print a specific row, we have couple of pandas methods:

1. `loc` - It only gets the label i.e. column name or features
2. `iloc` - Here i stands for integer, representing the row number
3. `ix` - It is a mix of label as well as integer (not available in pandas >=1.0)

Below are examples of how to use the first two options for a specific row:

1. `loc`

```python
df.loc[row,column]
```

For the first row and all columns:

```python
df.loc[0,:]
```

For the first row and some specific column:

```python
df.loc[0,'column_name']
```

2. `iloc`

For the first row and all columns:

```python
df.iloc[0,:]
```

For the first row and some specific columns i.e. first three cols:

```python
df.iloc[0,0:3]
```

Comment: Option 3 `ix` has been dropped from Pandas as of release 1.0.

Answer (score 12):

Use [`ix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) operator:

```
print df.ix[159220]
```

Comment: To quote the message this generates: 

DeprecationWarning: 
.ix is deprecated. Please use
.loc for label based indexing or
.iloc for positional indexing

See the documentation here:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated
  This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing imports until

Comment: This no longer works at all as of pandas 1.0 (released Jan. 29, 2020).

Answer (score 8):

If you want to display at row=159220

```py
row=159220

#To display in a table format, you can use with or without display()
df.iloc[row:row+1]
df.loc[row:row]       #Not recommended

#To display in print format, you can use with or without display()
df.iloc[row]
df.loc[row]       #Not recommended
```

Comment: ```print(df.loc[[index]])``` doesn't work with multiple sheets. I've tried ```df = pd.read_excel(file, ["sheet1", "sheet2", "sheet3"])``` and get an error: ```AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'loc']```

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you're calling `df.plot()`. That error indicates that you're trying to *plot* a frame that has no numeric data. The data types shouldn't affect what you `print()`.

Use `print(df.iloc[159220])`

Answer (score 1):

You can also index the index and use the result to select row(s) using `loc`:

```py
row = 159220          # this creates a pandas Series (`row` is an integer)
row = [159220]        # this creates a pandas DataFrame (`row` is a list)
df.loc[df.index[row]]
```

This is especially useful if you want to select rows by integer-location and columns by name. For example:

```py
rows = 159220
cols = ['col2', 'col6']
df.loc[df.index[row], cols]  # <--- OK

df.iloc[rows, cols]          # <--- doesn't work
df.loc[cols].iloc[rows]      # <--- OK but creates an intermediate copy
```

Answer (score 1):

**Print a specific row of a pandas DataFrame with example code with output:**

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'David', 'Emily'],
    'Age': [25, 30, 22, 35, 28],
    'Salary': [50000, 60000, 45000, 70000, 55000]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

row_i_want_to_print = 3
specific_row = df.iloc[row_i_want_to_print-1] # here I want to print row=3 which index=2. so I did row_i_want_to_print-1 to print actual row
print("Selected Row: ")
print(specific_row)
```

**Output:**

```
Selected Row: 
Name      Charlie
Age            22
Salary      45000
Name: 2, dtype: object
```