# Is there a way to directly print an attribute of an object stored in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I can't work out how to print some information from a DataFrame.  The DataFrame contains columns of strings, ints, and objects, and I'd like to print one of the pieces of information within the object alongside two other columns, sort of like:

```
df[[
    'Column of strings',
    'Column of ints',
    'Column of objects'.'String within object'
]]
```

But that syntax doesn't work.  Is there a simple way to do this without creating a new variable or having to iterate through df to pick out the items of interest one by one?  Help with a simple solution would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: check this answer it might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772362/how-to-print-a-specific-row-of-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: [df.select_dtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html)

Comment: Does `str(object)` return the string you are interested in? Are you only interested in how it **looks** when printed - you don't want to actually create a new column/dataframe?