# How to choose which rows to display from an excel sheet using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to be able to choose which rows I want to display when I print data from an excel sheet

```
data = pd.read_excel("TABLE.xlsx", usecols='D,E,F')
```

This allows me to choose which columns I want to display, what do I need to add to choose the specific rows?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772362/how-to-print-a-specific-row-of-a-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

```
# Below code only shows rows where the column 'D' values are greater than 5

data = pd.read_excel("TABLE.xlsx", usecols='D,E,F')
selected_rows = data[data['D'] > 5]

This is for selecting from D column.Similarly, use other indexing based on your requirement.
```

You can also use other boolean operators (<, >=, <=, ==, !=, etc.) to select rows based on different criteria, and combine multiple conditions using logical operators (& , | , ~ ).

Check this link for more help about boolean indexing
[Logical operators for Boolean indexing in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logical-operators-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas)

Comment: Please **don't** use bold text for your answers.