# How to get complete object from Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This is my panda dataframe object

```
                                    card.details
 1  [{'id': '3', 'weigh...
```

But here I am not getting the complete object. How to get the get the complete panda dataframe values .

My code structure looks like this

```
 from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
 import pandas as pd
 import eland as ed
 
 ed_data = ed.DataFrame("localhost:9200", "card_details",
                       columns=["card.details"]).es_query(elastic_search_query)

 pd_data = ed.eland_to_pandas(ed_data)
 dfe = pd.DataFrame(pd_data.values.flatten())
 print(dfe)
```

There are other field as well in the output of es query . How to get the complete dataframe object and not 2 fields and ... dots. Any suggestions

Comment: The object is there.  `dfe.loc[1, 'card.details']` to see it.  [See this post for some examples on modifying pandas output display](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38489412/2336654)

Comment: dfe.loc[1, 'card.details'] giving exception index out of bound

Comment: It's possible that your index are string values.  try `dfe.loc['1', 'card.details']`